# Every $3 \times 3$ complex matrix is unitarily similar to matrix of certain form

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

For what kinds of three-given-positions is it true that: for any matrix $A \in \mathbb C^{3 \times 3}$, $A$ is unitarily similar to a matrix whose entries at the given positions are $0$?

This problem occurred to me naturally when I was thinking about schur's Triangulization. I think if the given positions aren't in the same row or column, then the proposition stated above should be true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A quick observation: none of these three positions can lie on a diagonal, because positive definite matrices are unitarily similar only to positive definite matrices.

Therefore, up to simultaneous permutations or rows and columns, the three positions must have one of the following three alignments:
$$
X=\pmatrix{\ast&\ast&\ast\\ 0&\ast&\ast\\ 0&0&\ast},
\ Y=\pmatrix{\ast&\ast&\ast\\ \ast&\ast&0\\ 0&0&\ast}
\ \text{ or }\ Z=\pmatrix{\ast&0&\ast\\ \ast&\ast&0\\ 0&\ast&\ast}.
$$
Of course, by Schur triangulation, the first form is always possible. The second form is also possible, as it can be obtained from the first form by applying a further unitary similarity transform $(U\oplus1)X(U^\ast\oplus1)$ for some appropriate unitary $2\times2$ matrix $U$.

So, the only question that remains is whether every complex $3\times3$ matrix is similar to some matrix in the form of $Z$.